# Laravel - how to extract an array to variables and use them in blade

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

Can we extract an array in the laravel views?

for example consider this:

We've say 20 variables in a controller which we need to pass into **blade**, now of course we can pass these variables using compact like this:

```
return view('someview', compact('var_a', 'var_b', 'var_c', 'var_d' ....));
```

But is there way we can move all the variables in array and then pass it to blade and then somehow extract it in blade like this:

```
$data = array('var_a' => 'value', 'var_b' => 'value', 'var_c' => 'value', 'var_d' => 'value', );
return view('someview')->with($data);
```

then In blade access like this:

```
{{$var_a}} {{$var_b}} {{ $var_c}}
```

Like we have `extract()` function in PHP, which does the same, I'm just looking for same to use in blade

I don't wan't to access as index like this:

```
{{ $data['var_a'] }}
```

I've seen and inspired by similar syntax used in opencart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it's simple as you can do it like so

```
$data = ['var1' => 'value', 'var2' => 'value'];
```

then

```
return view('someview', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with several ways, I'll write 2 ways to do this

- **way 1:**

  in controller :

```
$data = array('var_a' => 'hello', 'var_b' => 'bye', 'var_c' => 'ok');
return view('someview', compact('data'));
```

then you have to use the `extract()` PHP inbuilt function (See this [link](https://phppot.com/php/php-array-extract/) for more information)
Then add the following code in `someview.blade.php` file:

```
@php
   extract($data)
@endphp

<h1>{{$var_a}}</h1><br>
<h2>{{$var_b}}</h2><br>
<h3>{{$var_c}}</h3><br>
```

- **way 2:**

  in controller :

```
$data = array('var_a' => 'hello', 'var_b' => 'bye', 'var_c' => 'ok');
return view('someview', $data);
```

and you don't have to do anything anymore, Larval itself will do the first way.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is Your Simple Solution

```
$data = array('var_a' => 'value of var_a', 'var_b' => 'value of var_b', 'var_c' => 'value of var_c', 'var_d' => 'value of var_d',);
return view('someview',$data);
```

and in Blade you can access

```
{{$var_a}} {{$var_b}} {{ $var_c}}
```